# Does a multivariate optimization problem "necessarily" require that $f\in C^{n}$?

Tags: optimization, definition

Apologies if this question might seem elementary but I am currently self-learning optimization.

In the formal definition of an unconstrained optimization problem, for a univariate function $f : \mathcal{U}\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, it is required that $f\in C$.

However, for the multivariate case where $f : \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$, is it sufficient that $f\in C^{2}$ or is it necessary for it to be in $C^{n}$

I am asking this because I know there are some optimality conditions in finding local minimizers which require that $f$, its first-derivative, and its second-derivative be well-defined. I am thankful for any answer or suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by $f \in C^n$ ? differentiable n times?

Comment: Yes$\text{$\quad$}$ @Aame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question since none of them, in the strict mathematical sense, are "necessary". If $f$ is $C^1$ then you can locate potential critical points (maxima/minima/saddle points) using the derivative/gradient of $f$. If $f$ is $C^2$ then you can use the Hessian (the double derivative, or gradient of the gradient) to assess whether it's a minima or a maxima. But sometimes the second derivative test is insufficient and and higher order derivative tests prevail ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test)). In this case of course it is useful that $f$ has higher order derivatives, but like I said they are not strictly necessary. So basically, the higher the $k$ in $C^k$ the better. But I would say that everyone would agree that $f$ has to be at least $C^1$ to have a good chance of solving an optimization problem.